# How to keep static variable values after switching apps in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that uses a printer by calling a url. The url call opens another app called passPRNT which performs the print job, and then passPRNT calls myappschema://another-url-with-results?var=val.

The problem is that after printing the static variables are lost or re-initiated, so I cannot keep track of what has been printed.

I have a class in print.dart:

```
class Print {
  static bool printing = false;
}
```

Then in main.dart:

```
if (!Print.printing)
{
  // this should only happen once
  // but since the value of Print.printing seems to reset when my app comes back to focus
  // this print job repeats forever
  Print.printing = true;
  openPassPRNTurl();
}
```

Comment: Save them on the device and restore them after the app is reopenned

Comment: @RémiRousselet so you're saying flutter is supposed to behave like this? Naturally I have considered that solution but it makes me really disappointed in flutter.

Comment: @RobinManoli you can create local variable to manage state of flag

Comment: @AnkitMahadik could you please elaborate on that? What do you mean?

Comment: @RobinManoli please check my answer may be that's the answer you looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can have flage value in local variable of class so variable will manage it's state

```
class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static bool printing = Print.printing;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() { 
    if ( !printing)
    { 
       printing = true;
      print("Hellooooo");
    }
    return _SomeScreenState();
  }
}
```